# Can't locate Segmentation error in a C++ program implementing the Huffman table

Tags: c++11, huffman-code

I've tried to implement a Huffman table here. I understand how it works and I don't really see anything wrong with the approach I used and there aren't any syntax errors. However, I seem to be getting a segmentation fault 11 error, and I'm not sure where exactly.

I've added comments to every section to indicate what happens where. Any form of assistance, as to which portion of the code I need to overlook would be really appreciated.

On trying to backtrace with a debugger, I got an error saying:

> solution  std::map with 4198576 elements error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x18

On further inspection, the error seems to be in the while statement while(x->data != var.first). Not sure how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


class HuffmanNode{
 public:
 char data;
 int count;
 HuffmanNode *left;
 HuffmanNode *right;
};


//Compare function for priority queue
class compare_function{
public:
bool operator()(const  HuffmanNode* one, const  HuffmanNode* two){
return one->count> two->count;
}

};

/*
Struct used for the final map which uses
ascii value as keys and contains 
*/
struct information{
int freq;
string code;

};


int main(){

//Helps build the huffman table
priority_queue<HuffmanNode*, vector<HuffmanNode*>,compare_function> 
huffman_table;

/*Use manual input
replace with file input later
Helps get the frequency count
*/
map<char, int> frequency;

string text = "What is your name";

for(char c: text)
    frequency[c]++;

/*Put the informaton from the map to the 
 priority queue */

 for(auto var: frequency){
    HuffmanNode* node= new HuffmanNode;
    node->data=var.first;
    node->count=var.second;
    node->left=nullptr;
    node->right= nullptr;
    huffman_table.push(node);

 }

//Building a tree
 HuffmanNode* combined= nullptr; // Declared outside as it can be used to combine with the last node in the priority queue
 while(huffman_table.size() >= 2){
    HuffmanNode * one = huffman_table.top(); // First minimum node
    huffman_table.pop(); // Popped out of the queue
    HuffmanNode*two = huffman_table.top(); //Second minimum node
    huffman_table.pop(); //Popped out of the queue

    //Combining the two nodes and re inserting to the table
    combined= new HuffmanNode();
    combined->data= '\0';
    combined->count= one->count+two->count;
    combined->left = one;
    combined->right = two;
    //Re-inset back to the table
    huffman_table.push(combined);

 }



/*The root of the table is the combination of the compared node and 
   the last node in the priority queue*/
 HuffmanNode* last = huffman_table.top();
 HuffmanNode* root= new HuffmanNode;
 root->data ='\0';
 root->count=combined->count+ last->count;
 root->left= combined;
 root->right = last;



//Map containing final solution
 map<char, information> solution;
 information i;


 //traverse the tree in search of the node and compute code
HuffmanNode* x = root;
string temp;
for(auto var: frequency){

   while(x->data != var.first)
   {
    if(x==nullptr)
        x=root;
    else if (x->count < var.second){
        temp=temp+"0";
        x=x->left;
    }
    else if(x->count > var.second){
        temp= temp+"1";
        x=x->right;
    }
   }
   i.code=temp;
   i.freq=var.second;
   solution[var.first]=i;
   x=root;
   temp="";

}
//Prints answer here
for(auto var: solution){
    cout<<var.first<<" "<<var.second.freq<<" "<<var.second.code;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? They are an essential tool for a dev, allowing you to you figure out problems like this without having to waste your and other people's time asking them to figure it what large amounts of code like this mean and do the debugging for you. _"I seem to be getting a segmentation fault 11 error and I'm not sure where exactly"_ With a debugger, you can stop at the site of the fault and then trace back from it, check variable values along the way, etc. I would start by learning that, rather than asking on SO at the first hurdle.

Comment: As a matter of fact I did, however I got an error saying "solution(variable) std::map with 4198576 elements<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x18>",  and I'm still unsure as to how to fix it. @underscore_d

Comment: When did you get that, when trying to backtrace? It would be good to [edit] that into your question, along with any other info you have on what you already tried.

Comment: `map<char...>` has 4198576 elements? That's a rather wide `char` type.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*The root of the table is the combination of the compared node and 
   the last node in the priority queue*/
 HuffmanNode* last = huffman_table.top();
 HuffmanNode* root= new HuffmanNode;
```

Well, your `huffman_table` has no elements, so `top()` throws. And why does it has no elements? Before you never added any to it.

Comment: +Joker_vD The while loop is from >=2, Hence when the table has the last element remaining, it breaks out of the loop.

Comment: @JasonMetr You never put anything into the `huffman_table` — re-read your own code.

Comment: @underscore_d The `top()` is called after the loop which was never executed, because, as I said, no nodes were ever added to the  `huffman_table` so it's alway been empty.

Comment: Okay, I figured out my mistake! I forgot to push the elements into the queue, however it still doesn't fix the error.